# Error 500 with X-Frame-Options and REST API

Tags: rest, x-frame-options

I send a post request that aims to update a file on Kofax TotalAgility. 
I obtain an error 500 and the following error message :

```
HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 500 Unknown Exception [Cache-Control: private, Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8, X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN, Date: Mon, 23 Dec 2019 12:49:29 GMT, Content-Length: 39] ResponseEntityProxy{[Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8,Content-Length: 39,Chunked: false]}}
```

Is this error message is resulting from this server setting : X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN ?

Comment: X-Frame-Options does typically not affect server behavior.

Comment: I found out that my JSON was not correct. Stupid mistake... 2 hours lost on a stupid stuff. I should learn to read API documentation